# How to define a derivative of a function at some point?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax

Consider a function

```
derivative[x_]:=D[Sin[x],x]
```

When calling it with some argument, like derivative[2], instead of $\cos(x)$ it gives me $\partial_{2}\sin(2)$. Is it possible to define a function in one string that first takes the derivative and then returns it at the given point? And to generalize this to an arbitrary function f, i.e.

```
derivative[f_,x_]:=D[f,x]
```

Comment: `Derivative[1][f][x]`, here f is a pure function. I think you want a function such as `derivative[f_,x_,x0_]` ?

Comment: @cvgmt : yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think simplest and cleanest way would be to use

```
derivative[f_] := f'
```

E.g. if you evaluate

```
derivative[Sin]
```

you get the pure function

```
Cos[#1] &
```

and therefore

```
derivative[Sin][x0]
```

returns

```
Cos[x0]
```

Comment: Oh this is much more elegant than my solution!   Does this generalise to arbitrary derivatives, e.g. `derivative[f_] := f^(1,0)` for `f[x_,y_] = Cos[x]Sin[y]` for example?

Comment: For that case you might want to take a look at Derivative. You could say derivative[f_] := Derivative[1,0][ f ]; Beware that in that case you need too invoke derivative[ Cos[#1] Sin[#2]& ], (or g[x_,y_] := Cos[x]Sin[y]; derivative[g] ) because your function takes 2 arguments and mathematica needs to know which one is the first argument and which one the second.

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue here is one of the order of operations.  Consider instead:

```
derivative[x_] := ( D[Sin[y],y] /. y -> x )
```

And, more generally,

```
derivative[f_, x_] := ( D[f[y], y] /. y -> x)
```